# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in Laravel 5

Tags: php, http, laravel, laravel-5

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('deactivatecountry', array(
            'as'   => 'deactivatecountry', 
            'uses' => 'CountriesController@deactivateCountry'
));
Route::post('deactivatestate', array(
            'as'   => 'deactivatestate', 
            'uses' => 'StatesController@deactivateState'
));
```

**Javascript**

```
function deactivateCountry(country_id) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {}
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","deactivatecountry", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("country_id=" + country_id);
}

function deactivateState(state_id) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {}
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","deactivatestate", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("state_id=" + state_id);
}
```

When the deactivateCountry function in my javascript is called, the code works perfectly fine. It calls the deactivateCountry method in the CountriesController and it deactivates the country as expected.

But when I call the deactivateState function, it throws a MethodNotAllowedHttpException and I have no idea why.

Both the country and the state have the same route and the functions are similar but one is working and the other is not.

Can somebody please help me with this? I have been sitting on this for a couple of hours now and I'm not able to figure out why this is happening

**Here is the error that I am getting when I call the deactiveState method**

```
1/1
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:
in RouteCollection.php line 207
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 194
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 142
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 716
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 160
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: I don't see any error here. Are you sure you are running the correct function?

Comment: You might have a conflicting route. Can we see your whole routes file please?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I have edited my question and the error that is thrown is now included.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I have edited my question and the complete routes is now included.

Comment: @Rohit Thanks. Can you verify by looking in your browser console that you are indeed making a POST request? Because the error stack says something about GET

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thank you for your time. :) I did debug the routecollection.php to see which route is trying to do a GET but there are no extra information I got other than the one that is being thrown by the browser. I will try the browser console now to see if I can find out something more and get back.

Comment: @Rohit you should also show the `StatesController@deactivateState` method

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I have updated my question with the StatesController@deactivateState method

Comment: @Rohit it doesn't help much. What `\App\Http\Helpers\Geographies\StatesHelper::deactivateState` does? Maybe it makes some redirection using GET method to not existing path?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I have debugged this and it is not even entering the deactivateState method. In the helper, I am just calling a method in my model and running a query to set my flag to 0 to deactivate the state.

Answer (score 2):

@MarcinNabiałek and @lukasgeiter. Thank you both for your time and patience with this question. I have been able to solve the problem. The change I made was in the **javascript**

```
function deactivateCountry(country_id) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {}
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","/deactivatecountry", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("country_id=" + country_id);
}

function deactivateState(state_id) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {}
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","/deactivatestate", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("state_id=" + state_id);
}
```

I added a / in front of the route. So in xmlhttp.open I changed it from `xmlhttp.open("POST","deactivatestate", true);` to `xmlhttp.open("POST","/deactivatestate", true);`

I got to this position when I checked the POST url which xmlhttp was requesting and i was different from the one I had specified which is why Laravel was assuming that it was a GET request instead of a POST.

Comment: So instead of calling an absolute path you were calling a relative path, the code you were running therefor must have been in a subfolder.